# Trasferring Arduino chip from prototype platform to a PCB (Serial Communication)

Tags: arduino, pcb, usb, serial

I have been working on a little project where my Arduino Uno sends the IMU sensor's data to the PC via serial (Printing the data on serial monitor. I ma planning the transfer the programmed Arduino chip (Atmega) from the prototype platform to a PCB. I have read that I just need a crystal and a couple of capacitor to run the already programmed Arduino chip on a PCB. And I could use the prototype platform to program the chip and transfer back o the PCB.

My question here, can the Arduino on the PCB still perform the serial communication with the PC? Does the PCB need extra components such as a USB-to-Serial converter in order to perform the serial communication? Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Transferring to PCB

See [How do I create a permanent application from something prototyped with Arduino?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/67112/2191) for general guidance. Doesn't cover serial comms specifically.

### Serial comms

For serial comms you can connect a suitable USB-to-serial cable such as an FTDI cable. You'd connect it to header pins on your PCB that you linked to the appropriate pins on the ATmega.

Or you can add the USB interface to your PCB design using the same FTDI FT232RL chip and support components used on the older Arduinos. See page 27 of the [data sheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf). I believe you can omit the level convertor (as you are connecting the ATmega IC not a +/- 12V serial device).
See also SparkFun's [breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/718) as an example.

See also ["ATmega328 hardcore"](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-atmega328-hardcore)

Comment: Dear RedGrittyBrick, thank you very much for the a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Arduino Uno, or any of the older versions, that still used the Atmega328 chip in a DIP package, you can do this.

You will need 1 of 2 things for serial communications with your computer.

If your computer has a hardware serial port built in, you will need to use a TTL-to-RS232 level converter chip.

If your computer does not have a hardware serial port, you will need a USB-to-serial chip.

Comment: Dear Jwygralak67,
I ma using a laptop with no hardware serial port, only USB ports. Should I use the following device(http://www.cytron.com.my/viewProduct.php?pcode=UC00B&name=USB%20to%20UART%20converter%20V2011) to connect to the computer?

Comment: That looks like it should work.